# canvg not working in Edge

Tags: javascript, html, svg, canvg

I am taking webpage screenshot of svg content using **canvg**. In *Chrome*, *Opera* and *IE11* it seems to work fine, however in *Edge* browser it only weirdly renders black background with no content on the canvas.
[Try it here in Edge browser](http://canvg.github.io/canvg/examples/index.htm)

Open the link above and try the following examples
1) soccer
2) floorplan

I am unable to find the problem. Apparently looks like Edge is not supported by canvg. I hope someone already found a solution for this. It will be a great help!

Answer (score 0):

There's more information about this issue here: https://github.com/canvg/canvg/issues/520

There is currently a merged PR that has not been released as mentioned in the issue and there's a workaround by monkey patching the code from that fix into the canvg code. You may want to subscribe to that issue so you know when the patch is released.